# Evaluation ring homomorphism is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field, and $K\subseteq F$ a subfield of $F$. Given $u\in F$, consider $K[u]$ the subring generated by $K\cup\{u\}$.

We define the evaluation in $u$ as $e_u:K[X]\to K[u]$ by $e_u(f)=f(u)$. Proof that $e_u$ is surjective ring homomorphism.

Homomorphism is clear, but I can't see why is it surjective.

Consider $a\in K[u]$. If $a\in K$, we can take $f(x)=a\in K[X]$ and $e_u(f)=a$

Any suggestion for the preimage of $a$ if $a\notin K$ ? I've thought $f(x)=x-u+a$ but we can't ensure $a-u\in K$, so we can't ensure $f(x)\in K[X]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You consider the subring $F_u$ of $F$ generated by $K\cup\{u\}$. This is just the set of all polynomial expressions in $u$ with coefficients in $K$:
$$K[u] = \{\sum_{i=0}^n k_iu^i\mid k_i\in K, n\geq 0\}.$$

First, $F_u\subseteq K[u]$, since $K[u]$ is a subring of $F$ containing $K$ and $u$, and $F_u$ is smallest with this property.

Second, $K[u]\subseteq F_u$, since all expressions $\sum_{i=0}^n k_iu^i$ are contained in the subring $F_u$ generated by $K$ and $u$.